# Filter mysql records by date where date>=3month

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

i want to filter mysql records from my blood donor table! where blood_donated_date >= 3month old.

[image: 1]

Comment: Greater than or equal to 3 months relative to _which_ other date?

Comment: and what's your question? you explained what you want to do but you didn't ask any question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select all records which are older than 3 months, use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `donor` WHERE `donateddate` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

If you want to select all records from the last 3 months, use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `donor` WHERE `donateddate` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```